# Animating width on mouse hover not working

Tags: jquery

```
$( ".menuicon" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '100px'
    }, 300);
});

$( ".menuicon" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '36px'
    }, 300);
});
```

The icon's width changed to 100px on mouse hover, but soon comes back to 36px with the mouse still on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `mouseleave` event, not `mouseover`:

```
$(".menuicon").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        width: '36px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Or better yet, combine the entire thing to use `hover`:

```
$(".menuicon").hover(
    function() { $(this).stop(true).animate({ width: '100px' }, 300); },
    function() { $(this).stop(true).animate({ width: '36px' }, 300); }
);
```

Comment: That worked. But the problem is, when I quickly mouse hover multiple times, the animation keeps stacking and it keeps on bouncing. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can use `stop(true)` to clear the animation queue. See my update

Answer (score 1):

Use **[mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)** in place of **[mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)** like,

```
$( ".menuicon" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '36px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Or try **[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** like,

```
$( ".menuicon" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '100px'
    }, 300);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '36px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".menuicon" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '100px'
    }, 300);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
       width: '36px'
    }, 300);
});
```